# gcp multiregion-region-zone relationship json/API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, region, zone, google-cloud-sdk

I am able to get all Multiregion and their respective zones from https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/

[image]

As shhown in pictures, right now there are 3 Multiregion available in GCP.

**Is there any API/JSON available for finding the relationship between MultiRegion - Region and Zone in GCP?**

Comment: I am not really sure what you are looking for and what you mean by "for finding the relationship between MultiRegion", there are two APIs regarding zones and regions you can make use of:
 https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zones/list, 
 https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regions/list, would you like to do the same to describe a multi-region?

Comment: This is region & zone. If you see the image from question, there are 3 multi-regions (very 1st line) - America, Europe and Asia-Pacific. I just wanted APIs to find which locations come under particular multi-region. Eg: Oregon, Lowa, South Carolina etc are locations come under Americas multi-region.

Comment: Reason for location-multiregion mapping is, in https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json , egress tiers (eg: "CP-COMPUTEENGINE-INTERNET-EGRESS-APAC-APAC" key in above page) (APAC means Asia Pacific) depends on multiregion.

Comment: This kind of API at the moment is not available, I will create a feature request on your behalf and I will provide you a link to follow the updates. Would you like to list all the multiregions  and from there to get the region and the zone. Let's say it would provide a list of dictionary (the region), each region contain an other list of dictionary (the zones). Disclaimer: I work for Google Cloud Platform Support

Comment: @GalloCedrone : thanks for the update and feature request. Is there any APIs for getting location from region? (https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/) Ex: Lowa is under us-center1.

Comment: @GalloCedrone : I think document have been updated. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations .. Thanks for your help ..

Comment: Welcome :), by the way didn't understand from your last message a point, are you fine with that document or you would still need the APIs?

Comment: @GalloCedrone : It would be good if we get APIs. Right now we have created our own API from document data. But it is not good solution, coz if document will update in future, we have to modify data in our script too.

Comment: @GalloCedrone : can we get jsons?

Comment: I opened the feature request, you should describe your use case in order to support its implementation! @Harsha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have created the Feature Request.

You will have to rely for a while on your solution since any kind of  the API implementation follows strict rules and rollout procedures.

You can follow the updates in the public issue tracker, I suggest you to star it to receives updates and notifications and place a comment saying why it would be useful in your case. The speed of the implementation depends as well on the attention raised.

- https://issuetracker.google.com/77801293

Comment: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851649/how-sku-based-pricing-in-gcp-work-for-different-currency-modes?